# How to use diffrent database's in one SSRS

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have two database and at first database have master table1 which have Id and name and another detail.
and in second data base have a table2. In that table i save the id  and another detail.
And i need to show SSRS report.These report will show Table1's- Name  and from Table2's Another detail related to Tabale1's Name .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two databases are on the same server,
you can use:

select fdt1.Name, fdt1.Detail as Detail1, fdt2.Detail as Detail2

from firstdatabase..table1 fdt1 join

seconddatabase..table2 fdt2

on fdt1.id=fdt2.id

If the databases are on different servers, you can create a linked server and use a four part naming convention to refer to the server the database is located on (as one option).

Comment: But i m using very credential database.In that we cant use query like this. By the way I solve my problem...Again thanks for the solution..